# Why does the nav go off the screen left side when the media query kicks in?

Tags: html, css, layout, media-queries

When the screen is below 450px the logo disappears to give the nav space, but the nav then goes about 20px off the left side of the screen.

http://codepen.io/briligg/pen/emwXaw?editors=110

I believe this is the relevant code - i might have included more than necessary. CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    img#logo {
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    }
    nav {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    }
}
div#top{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 130px;
        z-index: 5;

}
img#logo {
        border: 0;
        float: left;    
        width: 20%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-left: 2%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        max-width: 123px;
        }


nav {       position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            width: 70%;
            float: right;
            padding: 2%;
            height: 60px;
            max-height: 60px;
            margin: 5px 5px;
            }
nav button {
            padding: 0 4px;
            height: 28px;
            font: 16px;
}

nav button ul {
            position: relative;
            display: none;
}

nav button:hover ul, nav button:focus ul {
            display: block;
            z-index: 6;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 4px;
}

nav button:hover li, nav button:focus li {
            padding: 4px;
}
nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
            color: #9dab71;
}
```

And here is the relevant HTML:

```
<div id="top">
<a href="default.html"><img id="logo" src="http://www.briligg.com/images/briligg-loopless-blue.png" 
alt="briligg home" /></a>
<nav>
<button><a href="futuremoon.html#begin">Purpose</a></button>
<button><a href="moonvsmars.html">Moon vs Mars</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="moonvsmars.html#ambiance">Ambiance</a></li>
     <li><a style="border-bottom: 1px solid #666666;" href="moonvsmars.html#communication">Communication</a></li>
     <li><a href="thereandback.html">There and Back</a></li>
</ul>
</button>
<button><a href="beingthere.html">Being There</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="beingthere.html#domination">World Domination</a></li>
        <li><a href="beingthere.html#chickens">Chickens</a></li>
        <li><a href="beingthere.html#gravity">Down with Gravity</a></li>
        <li><a href="beingthere.html#moonstar">The Moonstar</a></li>
        </ul>
</button>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given the nav element a `min-width` of 100%... because of the way the box model works, adding padding and margin to that forces the element to be wider than the viewport.

You can fix it by adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your nav element. This will force any padding or border to be included as width. See more details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

I would suggest reading up on how the box model works at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) and adjusting your padding and margin accordingly.

Comment: hey that's great - i didn't know that property existed. I'd tried making padding and margin 0 but it hadn't helped.  Thanks! (Of course i'd had to make the nav min-width 100% so it wouldn't wrap onto 2 lines on a narrow screen.)